# Handle conference rooms

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the actual version of the Microsoft Graph API (v.1.10.0)
But I'm not able to get the list of conference rooms or get the list of events for a conference room.

Can anyone tell me which endpoint I have to use to handle conference room events? I can't find any information about conference rooms in v1 of Microsoft Graph.

Answer (score 0):

You can access rooms through the beta version of the graph. They are currently treated as a special instance of a person.

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/findRooms